# Clicking a button on a website within VB code

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control

I have located the button in VB code:

```
Form1.WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input").Item(3)
```

From this HTML code on the website:

```
<input value="Log In" tabindex="4" type="submit" id="u_0_b">
```

How can I make the selected button 'clicked'?

EDIT:

No worries just solved it with this:

```
Form1.WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input").Item(3).Focus()
SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}")
```

Thanks for the help, thought I'd post the solution in case anyone else has the same issue.

Comment: Can't you set runat="server" on the input?

Comment: Cast the control to Button and use AddHandler.

Comment: What do you want the button to do? Maybe there's a different approach.

Comment: The button is part of a website, I have found a way to enter details into the website but I need to make the button clicked so it will log in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As simple as this:

```
Form1.WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input").Item(3).RaiseEvent("onclick")
```

On second look, I noticed the button is a submit button. In such case, you need to use different method as it doesn't have direct `onclick`:

```
Form1.WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input").Item(3).InvokeMember("click")
```

Comment: This unfortunately didn't work, when I added in the code nothing seemed to happen the button didn't get clicked. I am doing something wrong?

Comment: YES! This works perfectly I am going to use this instead of what I just found as this seems a better way to do it, Thanks so much for the help!